# Math.pow in Java gives unexpected decimal precision

Tags: java, python, clojure

Please could someone help me with java floats. I have observed some inconsistency with java
for e.g

```
Math.pow(10.0,-2)==0.01
Math.pow(10.0,-3)=0.0010 (instead of 0.001)
Math.pow(10.0,-4)=1.0 E-4
printf("%g",Math.pow(10,-4)) =0.000100000
```

Whereas with Python:

```
10**-1=0.1
10**-2=0.01
10**-3=0.001
```

With Clojure 1.4

```
(Math/pow 10 -2) = 0.01
(Math/pow 10 -3) = 0.001
```

My question is how do I get a similar result in Java , when compared with Python
In otherword how do i get the exact result without any trailing zeros. Why are these trailing zeros added , is there any way to suppress them.

Comment: You haven't said how you're *displaying* the value in the first three lines. Given that all of this seems to be more about format than value, you need to give us the code you're using. A short but complete program demonstrating the problem would be useful.

Comment: Is your question about the internal precision of the results, or about the output when displaying?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easy to explain where the trailing zeros are coming from.

For `%g` it's simple: `%g` always displays 6 significant digits by default, so you will see

```
1.00000
0.100000
0.0100000
0.00100000
0.000100000
1.00000e-5
1.00000e-6
...
```

You can get rid of them by setting the precision to 1 significant digit, but you probably don't want to since that would also round 2.5 to 3, for example.

Doing a `println` directly shows the representation of the result (a `double`) as defined by [`Double.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString%28double%29):

> the result is a string that represents the sign and magnitude (absolute value) of the argument. [...] for the magnitude *m*:

[...]

> If *m* is greater than or equal to 10<sup>-3</sup> but less than 10<sup>7</sup>, then it is represented as the integer part of *m*, in decimal form with no leading zeroes, followed by '.' ('\u002E'), followed by one or more decimal digits representing the fractional part of *m*.

[...]

> If *m* is less than 10<sup>-3</sup> or greater than or equal to 10<sup>7</sup>, then it is represented in so-called "computerized scientific notation." Let *n* be the unique integer such that 10<sup>*n*</sup> ≤ *m* < 10<sup>*n*+1</sup>; then let *a* be the mathematically exact quotient of *m* and 10<sup>*n*</sup> so that 1 ≤ *a* < 10. The magnitude is then represented as the integer part of *a*, as a single decimal digit, followed by '.' ('\u002E'), followed by decimal digits representing the fractional part of *a*, followed by the letter 'E' ('\u0045'), followed by a representation of *n* as a decimal integer, as produced by the method `Integer.toString(int)`.

[...]

> How many digits must be printed for the fractional part of *m* or *a*? There must be at least one digit to represent the fractional part, and beyond that as many, but only as many, more digits as are needed to uniquely distinguish the argument value from adjacent values of type double.

Hence you see

```
1.0
0.01
0.0010
1.0E-4
9.999999999999999E-6
1.0E-6
...
```

**So how to get rid of the trailing zeros?**

One way is to use `BigDecimal`, which has a [`stripTrailingZeros()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#stripTrailingZeros%28%29) method.
But you have to be careful how you use it:

```
System.out.println(BigDecimal.TEN.pow( -4 ,MathContext.DECIMAL64).stripTrailingZeros());
```

will print the expected

```
0.0001
```

but

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(Math.pow(10,-4)).stripTrailingZeros());
```

will print

```
0.000100000000000000004792173602385929598312941379845142364501953125
```

because that happens to be the exact value of the `double` that is closest to 10<sup>-4</sup>.

If you don't want to do all your math in `BigDecimal`s, then you can get a string representation of rounded result with `%g` (which gives you a chance to control the precision), make a `BigDecimal` out of it, and print the result:

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal( String.format("%g", Math.pow(10,-4) ) ).stripTrailingZeros());
```

Comment: System.out.println(new BigDecimal( String.format("%g", Math.pow(10,-4) ) ).stripTrailingZeros())

Comment: @ControlAltDel use the `@` notation to make sure George is notified.

Comment: @George who was that comment for?

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is just with display, you can use DecimalFormat and '#' http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Comment: System.out.println(new BigDecimal( String.format("%g", Math.pow(10,-10) ) ).stripTrailingZeros()) , wont this result in scientific format representation (1E-10). What if the result should be in fixed format 0.0000000001

Comment: @George Then use `System.out.println( new BigDecimal( String.format("%g", Math.pow(10,-10) ) ).stripTrailingZeros().toPlainString() )`. See [`BigDecimal.toPlainString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toPlainString%28%29).